# Sphers and Hemispheres and its sequence

Tags: combinatorics

I have Some hemispheres of different radius. Now the interesting fact is that i have both Upper hemispheres and lower hemispheres and i can use them to combine and form a Complete new sphere of Radius R but the necessary criteria is both the hemispheres i.e. upper and lower need to be also of same radius R. And lastly i can put the smaller spheres inside the bigger ones to form a sequence.

So now the question is to find the no. of ways forming a N-Sequence given that i have some upper hemispheres and some lower hemispheres all whose radius maybe different and will be provided.

Example :
1 2 3   Upper Hems.
1 1 3 2   Lower hems.

the answers are as follows
2 sphere concentric - 5 (2 + 2 + 1)
3 sphere concentric - 2 (1 + 1)
4 sphere concentric - 0
Note : The sphere with Radius 1 can be formed in two different ways because we have two lower hems. of radius 1 and hence the ans.

So guys this is a question of combination and permutation and i am weak at that so if i could get some help here. please help me to get the logic of the combination and help me to derive some basic formula for this if possible. or at least how can i approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer you share suggests, you can break up via cases.  How many ways can you have one total sphere?  Two total spheres?  Three total spheres?  etc...

In general, suppose you have the following two multisets:

$\{\alpha_1 \cdot 1, \alpha_2\cdot 2,\dots,\alpha_k \cdot k\}$ and $\{\beta_1\cdot 1, \beta_2\cdot 2,\dots,\beta_k \cdot k\}$  where the first multiset corresponds to the multiset of upper hemispheres, the second multiset corresponds to the lower hemispheres, $\alpha_i$ denotes the number of upper hemispheres of radius $i$, and $\beta_j$ similarly denotes the number of lower hemispheres of radius $j$.

If by "$N$-Sequence" you mean that there must be exactly $N$ spheres, then skip below to the generalization at $(\dagger)$.  Otherwise, if you are looking to count the number of sequences of any length, read on.

For one sphere, pick which radius it is and which upper and which lower hemisphere are used to form it.  There are $\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\beta_i$ number of ways of accomplishing this.

For two spheres, pick which two radii they are, and for each pick which upper and lower hemispheres are used to form them.  There are $\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=i+1}^k \alpha_i\beta_i\alpha_j\beta_j$ number of ways of accomplishing this.

At this point we see the pattern.

$(\dagger)$ In general, for $N$ spheres we will need to pick which $N$ radii to use and which corresponding upper and lower hemispheres to use for each radii.  There are then $\sum\limits_{S\subseteq [k],~|S|=N} ~\prod\limits_{i\in S} \alpha_i\beta_i$ total number of ways of accomplishing this.

For the total number of sequences of any length, there are:

$\sum\limits_{N=1}^{k}\sum\limits_{S\subseteq [k],~|S|=N} ~\prod\limits_{i\in S} \alpha_i\beta_i$ total possibilities.

In your small example, with the multiset of upper hemispheres being $\{1,2,3\}$ and lower hemispheres being $\{1,1,2,3\}$, we have for one sphere: $1\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1 = 4$ number of ways, for two spheres we have $1\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 2+2+1=5$ number of ways, and for three spheres we have $1\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1=2$ total number of ways, for a total number of $4+5+2=11$ number of possibilities.

---

*Note:* If the "empty" sequence is allowed as well, then simply add one to the grand total, or adjust the limits on the outermost sum to start from zero instead (remembering that the empty product is equal to one by definition).

*Further Note:* If your set of radii is not a subset of the natural numbers, the same logic applies.  So long as the set is totally ordered and countably finite, you can form an easy bijection to the natural numbers and approach that way.

*Final Note:* The formula described above happens to be general enough to not require each $\alpha_i$ and each $\beta_i$ to be nonzero.  Any time that one is zero, it will contribute nothing to the total sum, which makes sense since you could not have formed a complete sphere of that radius without both halves.

Comment: Your second Generalized solution is the one i am looking for but could you help me,   for two spheres we have $1\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1 = 2+2+1=5$ number of ways as i said i am weak in combinations could you please help me how did you get this. please be brief. Even for three Spheres one.

Comment: It is not using combinations or permutations, this is multiplication principle.  I asked myself, "what ways can I pick two radii for the spheres."  It could have been done as a radius 1 and a radius 2, or a radius 1 and a radius 3, or a radius 2 and a radius 3.  From there, I asked myself, "if one of the spheres is of radius 1 and the other sphere is of radius 2, how many ways?"  By multiplication principle, there are $1\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 1$ number of ways (pick which upper hemisphere of radius 1, pick which lower hemisphere of radius 1, pick which upper hemisphere of radius 2, etc...)

Comment: Continuing over all possibilities gives the result.